# populate dropdownlist with all numbers in between 2 numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAge" runat="server"/>

Label ages = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Ages");

//The value ages returns is different every time but it will be in this format
// 3 - 11
```

So i would like to grab the 3 from the left of the dash and then grab the 11 from the right of the dash and populate my dropdownlist with the values of 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 if possible just not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetAgesBetween(string agesText) {
    var parts = agesText.Split('-');
    var start = int.Parse(parts[0].Trim());
    var end = int.Parse(parts[1].Trim());
    return Enumerable.Range(start, 1 + end-start);
}
```

You can use that method to retrieve the numbers and use them to populate the drop down list.

Hope it helps

Comment: Looks fine to me, though I'd have probably gone for Enumerable.Range(start, 1 + end-start) instead of the for loop.

Comment: @Tim - If you use this option, you just have to set the DataSource  to the IEnumerable that's being returned and then call ddlAge.databind() to populate your your DropDownList

Comment: ended up going with  ddlAgeRange.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(myStartAge, 1 + myEndAge - myStartAge); but used this code as reference to lead me to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is in VB, but you can convert it in C#. This is just so that you get an idea as to how you can approach this problem. Here is the code:

```
     Dim ageData() As String = ages.split("-".ToCharArray())

     If ageData.Count = 2 AndAlso IsNumeric(ageData(0).Trim) AndAlso IsNumeric(ageData(1).Trim) Then
        For i As Integer = CInt(ageData(0)) To CInt(ageData(1).Trim) Step +1
           ddlAge.Items.Add(i)
        Next
     End If
```